# how to create json object to object feting result php query

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
                            $pstring = "select distinct p.maincode,c.cname,s.sect_code,sect_name,markcode,trandate,ldcp from price p,company c,
                            comp_sector s,sector se where
                            p.maincode=c.maincode and p.subcode=c.subcode
                            and p.maincode=s.maincode and p.subcode=s.subcode and s.sect_code=se.sect_code
                             and c.dateto is null and markcode='RD'
                            and trandate='2020-06-15'
                            order by sect_name,maincode desc ";
                            
                            
                            $res= call_qry($con,$pstring);
                        $count = 0 ;




                        $dataobject = array();

                        $res= call_qry($con,$pstring);
                        while($nt=call_a_ary($res))
                        {
                            
                                $dataobject[$count][value0]= $nt['cname'];
                                 $dataobject[$count][value1]= $nt['ldcp'];
                                 $dataobject[$count][value2]= $nt['sect_name'];
                                     
                           
                           $count = $count + 1 ;


                        }



        $post_data = json_encode(array('$nt['sect_name']' => $dataobject), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

        echo($post_data);
```

I want this type of JSON created from PHP MySQL code what I'm mistake in this coding. I also showing JSOn file code how can I get result for this code
I have tried many ways but could not get that. Can anyone help me doing that?

```
{
  "Autmobile": {
    "AL Ghazi": 13992,
    "Atlas Honda": 82413,
    "Dewan ": 198210,
    "Ghandara": 20,
    "Hinopak": 19131
  },
  "Banks": {
    "Allied": 128296,
    "Summit": 6846,
    "Askari": 32583,
    "Bank ALfalah": 387081,
    "Bankislami": 25755,
    "Samba": 329196,
    "Faysal": 4000
  }
}
```

Comment: `array('$nt['sect_name']' =>` <- that's a syntax error. Remove the quotes around the variable: `array($nt['sect_name'] =>`

Comment: but I want to create this type of JSON how can I do that

Comment: What variables contains what info? I can see that you're fetching a lot of columns in your SELECT but only seem to need three.

Comment: I want only sector name, company name and value .sector name is Bank, the company name is Allied and value is 128296 in display in  JSON format I'm trying this but did not get these format result any help

Answer (score 0):

```
while($nt=call_f_ary($res)){
    $sect_name =$nt['sect_name'];
    $cname =$nt['cname'];
            
    $dataobject[$sect_name][$count]= $cname  . ": " . $nt[6];
    $count = $count + 1 ;

   }
  $data=json_encode($dataobject,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Json_force_object convert from array to object with indexes